# `DateList` hour format

Tags: date-and-time

I cannot find it in the documentation, what is the default form of hour in the `DateList` when the form `{y,m,d,h,m,s}` is used. I would assume 24 hour system since there is no `am/pm` specification, but it is american software so I am not sure...

Comment: why don't you just try it and see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the 24h format. This can be easily checked by running:

```
dates = {"04/04/2022 6:20:23 PM", "04/04/2022 6:20:23",
  "04/04/2022 6:20:23 AM", "04/04/2022 18:20:23"};
DateList /@ dates

(* {{2022,4,4,18,20,23.}, {2022,4,4,6,20,23.}, {2022,4,4,6,20,23.}, {2022,4,4,18,20,23.}} *)
```

Note that the hour format accepts hours >24, which then gets added to the day in the output.

```
DateList[{2022, 4, 4, 26, 20, 23}]
(* {2022,4,5,2,20,23.} *)

DateList[{2022, 4, 4, 45, 20, 23}]
(* {2022,4,5,21,20,23.} *)
```